# How to resize a view controller in Swift 3 Cocoa

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, resize, viewcontroller

So I'm trying to resize a view controller when a button is clicked, but I'm having trouble. Here's my code:

```
func resizeWindow() {
    let num = 1000
    var windowFrame = mainWindow.frame
    let oldWidth = windowFrame.size.width
    let oldHeight = windowFrame.size.height
    let toAdd = CGFloat(num)
    let newWidth = oldWidth + toAdd
    let newHeight = oldHeight + toAdd
    windowFrame.size = NSMakeSize(newWidth, newHeight)
    mainWindow.setFrame(windowFrame, display: true)
}
```

I'm getting an error that says, "Value of type 'NSView' has no member 'setFrame'" (for the last line of code). I know that means that I probably need to replace `setFrame` with something else, but I'm not sure what. If you wouldn't mind helping me with this, I'd appreciate it! If you have any better suggestions, I'm open to that too :-) Thanks!

Comment: what is windowFrame? please show more code

Comment: windowFrame is a variable that simply holds all the properties that will be applied to mainWindow (which is the actual view controller)